# Batch file to output MD5 hash to a text file starting at a specific directory

Tags: batch, batch-file, md5sum

```bash
@echo off

set "src_dir=C:\Users\\Documents\projects\Config\ABC"
set OUTFILE="C:\Users\Documents\Scriptoutput.txt"

echo %OUTFILE%
pushd %cd%
cd %src_dir%

for /r %%f in (*) do (  
      (
        <nul set /p ".= %%~dpnxf," 
        certutil -hashfile "%%f" MD5 | find /V ":"
      ) >>%OUTFILE%  
   )
```

Out file content now:

```
C:\Users\Documents\Projects\Config\common\abc.csv,e71073e6906e06223d184fcd91124aad
C:\Users\Documents\Projects\Config\common\def.csv,6c3f42be2f7a19a31f2002accab8273d
C:\Users\Documents\Projects\Config\common\ahi\ghi.csv,d62d1612d82eff53038ccbd4eb32a81f
C:\Users\Documents\Projects\Config\common\ahi\ert.csv,8425dbd884c27a0ba4615ef5c45b97e5
```

Expected:

```
Config\common\abc.csv,e71073e6906e06223d184fcd91124aad
Config\common\def.csv,6c3f42be2f7a19a31f2002accab8273d
Config\common\ahi\ghi.csv,d62d1612d82eff53038ccbd4eb32a81f
Config\common\ahi\ert.csv,8425dbd884c27a0ba4615ef5c45b97e5
```

Comment: So your format is set by the expression `%%~dpnxf`, which is saying use the drive letter (d), the path (p), the name (n), and the extension (x). also note that `f` indicates a fully qualified path, but it does seem like its being properly overridded by the %%f variable value instead. here is a list of options for parameter expansion: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html

Answer (score 3):

```bash
@echo off

subst .: "%UserProfile%\Documents\Projects"
cd /d .:\ && 2>nul call del /q /f /a: ".:\Output.txt"

for /f delims^= %%i in =;(' where /r . *.* ^| find /v /i "\Output.txt" ');= do set "_path=%%~pnxi" && <nul =;( 
     call set /p ".=%%_path:~1%%," & certutil -hashfile "%%~fi" MD5 | find /v ":" );= >>".:\Output.txt"

type ".:\Output.txt" & cd /d "%~dp0" & subst /d .:
```

---

- Or specifically list the `*.csv` files if this is your case, optionally, you can also list more extensions with: **`where /r . *.xlsx *.csv`**:

```bash
@echo off

subst .: "%UserProfile%\Documents\Q1833755\Projects"
cd /d .:\ && 2>nul call del /q ".:\Output.txt"

for /f delims^= %%i in =;(' where /r . *.csv ');= do set "_path=%%~pnxi" && <nul =;( 
     call set /p ".=%%_path:~1%%," & certutil -hashfile "%%~fi" MD5 | find /v ":" 
    );= >>".:\Output.txt"
```

---

**1.** Create a drive to replace your root folder, like `.:`

**2.** Associate it with a character that will prevent graphical access (Windows/Explorer)

**3.** Enter that drive, list your files and remove the first character with substring in varible

**4.** Finally, remove the created drive, list/check your output

---

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`Where /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html)
- [`Find /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

  - [`For /F commands`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

  - [`||`](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [Commands Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [`Set variable=variable:substrings` | DOS - String Manipulation](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)
- [**`Subst /?`** Substitute a drive letter for a network or **`local path`**.](https://ss64.com/nt/subst.html)